# What is the first instance of teleportation using a machine (aka transporter) in Sci-Fi movies or TV?

Tags: movie, tv, history-of, teleportation

I know of only a few uses of teleportation prior to *Star Trek*'s (TOS) transporter that appeared in movies or TV shows.

**What is the earliest example of teleportation by a machine, shown in a movie or on TV?**?

---

Those that I know of are:

1. Movie:  *[The Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fly_(1958_film))* (1958)
2. TV:  *Outer Limits*, season 1, Episode 1: [*The Galaxy Being*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Galaxy_Being) (1963)
3. TV:  *Outer Limits*, Season 1, episode 28: [*The Special One*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Special_One_(The_Outer_Limits)) (1964)

I think there are others but do not know of any.  Technically, it does not have to be a Sci-Fi movie or TV show but if it has teleportation it seems to come under that category.

There is another *Outer Limits* episode in the original series where several residential blocks (homes and home residents) were teleported from Earth to another planet but that was an incident merely to set up the story and it could have been executed by any other means, including space magic.  In fact, even in item (3) of my list, the teleportation of Mr. Zeno as shown is incidental to the story and not existing as an actual machine like the movie *The Fly* and episode 1 of *Outer Limits*.

Anything that appears after the advent of *Star Trek* (TOS) is not of any interest to me.

Comment: Curious as to why I was marked down.  Since this is my first post here, could I have violated policy or are you just unhappy with the question?

Comment: Not my vote but "List" questions aren't *generally* encouraged...as they temd to be tood broad.

Comment: What you _could_ do, is asking for the _first_ example of teleportation in movies or on TV. We have more questions like that here.

Comment: Are you only interested in cases with a 'scientific' explanation or for example would magical transportation be interesting? This site includes fantasy as well as sci fi

Comment: @JeremyFrench   Well, I was primarily interested in cases where an actual machine used for teleportation was part of the story.  I noted in my question that the Outer Limits Episode "The Special One" portrayed a kind of teleportation but no actual machine or device was used or mentioned so it skirted on the periphery of my main interest.

Comment: FYI, your question has just been reopened.

Comment: If there's an answer that you find "best", you can accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote count.

Answer (score 11):

[This article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihneaf-qLXAhUE3IMKHXqRAHUQFgg9MAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fio9.gizmodo.com%2Fthe-tragic-demise-of-science-fictions-greatest-idea-1642504729&usg=AOvVaw3lws1gQ7XdYLEL-ZS4gIRf) indicates that both *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century* and *Flash Gordon*, in their serial formats, included some occurrences of matter transmission.  I couldn't find specifics from *Flash Gordon*, but [this article](https://filesofjerryblake.com/2013/09/05/buck-rogers/) includes an actual frame capture of the teleportation machine used in the Buck Rogers serial of 1939, almost twenty years earlier than the Vincent Price version of *The Fly*.  And, thanks to @WinchellChung, here's [a video clip of that machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv5BCGSea14) in action.

Comment: Nice find! -- beats mine by almost 2 decades... :)

Comment: Thanks.  Buck Rogers and Flash Gordon were the first thoughts in my mind when I read the question, it was just a matter of finding actual proof.

Comment: Here is a video clip of the Buck Rogers teleportation machine in action
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv5BCGSea14

Comment: I think that first linked article is wrong about the Flash Gordon film serials, having watched them all recently--the only teleportation I saw was [Queen Azura](https://flashgordon.fandom.com/wiki/Queen_Azura) in the serial "Flash Gordon's Trip to Mars", but that was thanks to a magical sapphire she wore, not a technological "matter transmitter". So Buck Rogers may well be the earliest example.

Comment: @Hypnosifl You might well be correct -- I haven't the personal experience to refute the article, however, and we have the video evidence confirming the *Buck Rogers* appearance and machine operation.

Comment: I did a little more research and discovered there was a scene in the first episode of *Flash Gordon's Trip to Mars* (1938) that features what *might* be some sort of technological matter transmission--5 minutes in at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ2HUfD0QSw&t=301s Zarkov is speculating that other planets may have means of travel more advanced than rockets, maybe at the speed of light, then we see a shot of a beam emanating from Mars and striking Earth, and two Martians appear. Not 100% clear if this is technology or magic though, as I said the queen of Mars has magic powers in the serial.

Comment: Rewatching the rest of that first episode I think it is fairly clear that the beam that materializes the Martians on Earth is technological rather than magical--we [later](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqHmSW7s90k&t=215s) see an identical looking beam traveling from Mars to Earth, and it's [said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqHmSW7s90k&t=300s) to be extracting "Nitron" from Earth's atmosphere (maybe by teleporting it to Mars?) We also see a [big telescope-like device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqHmSW7s90k&t=409s) the beam is emanating from on Mars.

Answer (score 9):

There is an very good article [here](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/T/teleportation.html), about the origins of the teleportation in sci-fi.

> Perhaps the earliest recorded story a matter transmitter was Edward Page Mitchell's "The Man Without a Body" in 1877. In this story, a scientist invents a machine that breaks down the atoms of a cat and sends them by wire to a receiver, where the animal is reassembled alive and well.

The story can be found on [this](http://www.forgottenfutures.com/game/ff9/tachypmp.htm) page.

There are a few cases over the next few decades, perhaps most notibly [The Disintegration Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Disintegration_Machine) 1927, by Arthur Conan Doyle

However teleportation seems to become quite popular in the 1950s appearing in several novels and short stories:

- [The mixed men](http://www.conceptualfiction.com/the_mixed_men.html) 1952
- [A Tunnel in the sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_in_the_Sky) 1955
- [The Stars My Destination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination) 1957
- [The Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fly_(George_Langelaan)) 1958
- [the Enemy Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enemy_Stars) 1959

(This list is not intended to be exhaustive)

So certainly by the time Star Trek was created (1966), the idea of a transporter was well known in sci-fi.

Comment: With the exception of "The Fly" as a movie that I mentioned in my question, the above references are all to written works, not movies or TV.  I specifically wanted answers focused as productions in movie or TV.  I am not interested in short stories, novels, and other written material.  In fact, I assumed that teleportation stories would even be somewhat numerous in written work but since I am not a SciFi reader, I actually don't know.  This is my first and probably last post here trying to find an answer to a discussion a few  of us had at a recent party.  It may be the wrong forum.

Comment: My bad. Missed the 'in movies or tv' in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The first known use of the word Teleport in a fiction story was published in the Hawaiian Gazette on October 23, 1878.

[image: Hawaiian Gazette]

In movies the 1939 *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century* serial film adaptations of the comic books of the same name used [teleportation instead of elevators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv5BCGSea14).

Answer (score 1):

The May 3rd, 1957 episode "[The Phony Alibi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0506631/)" from "[The Adventures of Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventures_of_Superman_(TV_series))" seems to have predated The Fly slightly, with a teleportation system that sends people over the telephone.

Stealing from the TvTropes Description:

> Bungling Inventor Professor Pepperwinkle creates a system for transporting people through telephone wires. As usual with Pepperwinkle, a gang of crooks befriends the naive professor, then uses his invention for evil; they commit crimes in Metropolis, then phone themselves to distant cities and make sure plenty of people see them to set themselves up with a (seemingly) perfect alibi.

Comment: Actually, I remember that Superman episode!

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the ones that you already have listed (As you say, the Outer Limits ones are semi questionable, and The Fly is probably the earliest appearance anyway), there are a couple of other candidates:

- *[The Projected Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Projected_Man)* - British film, where a scientist attempts teleportation by laser which goes horribly wrong - Released summer of 1966
- [*Twilight Zone - Valley of the Shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_the_Shadow) - Girl dematerializes and rematerializes dog with a device - Air date 1.17.1963

There are others around the same time frame, but all post date ST:TOS by at least a year or two.

Answer (score 0):

The 1956 movie "Forbidden Planet" (at 4 minutes into the movie) has a teleport system used for 5 men.  This was before *The Fly* or *Star Trek*.

Comment: Of course this isn’t as early as the 1939 answer of Buck Rogers mentioned in another answer though. Also if you could [edit] in some evidence, screenshot, video clip) if possible showing this that would be great.

Comment: ummmm, are you sure? I was under the impression those were decelerator platforms, to allow the crew to survive transition from faster-than-light travel into normal space travel. Not teleportation devices.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-57D#Forbidden_Planet_production

Comment: That is not a teleport system but it was for protection from rapid and quick de-acceleration from FTL speed.

Answer (score -1):

Doctor Who featured a number of teleportation devices over the years. The first occurrence is in a 1964 story, "The Keys of Marinus"

Comment: This answer does not even predate the example given in the question.

Comment: When it comes to Dr. Who, the TARDIS is itself a teleportation device, is it not?

Comment: @JWT while a tardis may technically teleport in a broad dictionary sense - a star trek or fly style transporter in the spirit of this discussion should be something analogous to radio or television for sound and picture transmission but for matter.  Plus now that I think about it - a TARDIS does travel from one destination to another so it doesn't teleport any more than a car does - its just traveling in a time vortex continuum until it shifts back into regular space.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Fair enuf.  In that respect the TARDIS' Time-Vortex is like Star Wars'  Hyperspace.  There is a (relative) transit time that the travelers experience.  When the travelers emerge they are notably older, regardless of the time they arrive relative to when they left.  Whereas with a teleporter the traveler does not experience a transit time.  Right?  Time Travel, eh?